# Can i refresh a table inside a modal in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, laravel

I have a Laravel project and it has a modal with 2 forms. One of them is a form that sends the date to server to select data from database and the other makes an insert via Model, but I want to achieve is to only refresh the table with the new data in the database without refreshing the whole page.

Is there a way to achieve this without using AJAX or should I just use it?

```
<div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center align-content-center align-self-center">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end align-content-end align-self-end">
                        <h4 style="color: rgb(0,0,0);padding: 0px;padding-top: 6px;">Justificar Pagamentos</h4>
                    </div><button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></button>
                </div><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
               
                <form name="date" method="POST" action="{{ url('data-fatura') }}" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                        <input type="date"  name="dateInicio"  class="form-control" style="  width: 170px;" value="<?php echo date('Y-01-01') ?>"/>
                        <span style="margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 10px;">Até</span>
                        <input type="date" name="dateFim" value="<?php echo date('Y-12-31') ?>" class="form-control" style="  width: 170px;"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin-left: 14px;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                                  </div>
                </form>


               <form name="single-file" method="POST" action="{{ url('single-file') }}" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 19px;color: #000000;">
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                            <div class="card card-body"><a>Passo Nº1 - Selecione o(s) documento(s) que deseja justificar (confirme o intervalo de datas)</a><a>Passo Nº2 - &#39;Escolher Ficheiro&#39; para fazer upload do justificativo</a><a>Passo Nº3 - Conclua clicando no botão &#39;Submeter&#39;</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     

                    <div class="table-responsive table mt-2" id="dataTable-1" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTable_info" style="margin-bottom: 50px;max-height:5cm">
                        
                        
                        
                        <table class="table table-striped table-sm my-0" id="dataTable">
                            <thead class="text-nowrap">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 339px;">Documento</th>
                                    <th class="text-right" style="width: 150px;">Descrição</th>
                                    <th style="width: 209px;text-align: right;">Valor Pendente</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">Justificar</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($faturas as $fatura)
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="my-auto" style="width: 154px;">{{ $fatura->DOCUMENTO }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-right">{{ $fatura->DATA }}</td>
                                    <td style="width: 138px;min-width: 128px;text-align: right;">{{ $fatura->VLPENDE }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-right my-auto" style="width: 154px;"><input type="checkbox" name="faturas[]" value="{{ $fatura->HASHDOC }}" /></td>
                               </tr> 
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr></tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>   



                    </div>
                    <div class="d-inline-flex justify-content-center align-items-center align-content-center align-self-center">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="file" />
                    </div>
                    @error('file')
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center align-content-center align-self-center" style="text-align: right;">
                        <div class="spinner-border text-info"></div><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" style="margin-left: 14px;">Submeter</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah you should use AJAX

Comment: Ty but i got the answer working!